# Installing 13.04 on a win 8 PC

Tags: installation

Can I install Ubuntu 13.04 on a windows 8 HP computer with the UEFI? If so are there any special things I must do to insure the UEFI doesn't block the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is compatible with UEFI and systems that originally shipped with Windows 8. Be sure to download the 64-bit copy of Ubuntu to ensure compatibility. You shouldn't need to take any additional steps to install on a UEFI machine.

While not strictly necessary, you may want to disable Secure Boot in your computer's BIOS settings, if possible. Ubuntu can be installed on a system with Secure Boot enabled, but an installation without it will be easier to manage.